# Creating device admin app with delphi - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main

Tags: android, delphi, kiosk, device-admin

I am new to android development and I am trying to create a KIOSK application for android with Delphi Tokyo 10.2.

This is what I am trying to do:
The app will have two buttons, one to open an app and the other to close the application after entering a password. This app should not not let the user to open any other apps.

What I have done :
I am able to make an app which can be listed under the Securrity > Device Administrators in android. But the application crashes when I open it

I understand to whitelist the required application one has to access the devicepolicymanager, and to do that the app must be a deviceadmin, and for an app to be a device admin, the manifest must specify the permission MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS. Also an class inherited from DeviceAdminReceiver (in android sdk) has to be registered receiver in this app.

I used the following to get Delphi equivalent classes for DeviceAdminReceiver.

```
java2op -classes android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver -unit untDeviceAdminReceiver
```

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.DeviceAdmin01"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="DeviceAdmin01" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">



        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"                 
                  android:label="DeviceAdmin01"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                  android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                  android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Following is the complete code of my from. This is not coded to do anything. I am trying just to make it run as a first step to make a kiosk application.

```
unit untMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, untDeviceAdminReceiver,
  Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero, Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  AndroidAPI.Helpers, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyReceiver = class (TJDeviceAdminReceiver)
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure onEnabled(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
    procedure onDisabled(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;

  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FMyListener : TMyReceiver;
    FDeviceAdminReceiver : JDeviceAdminReceiver;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TMyReceiver }

constructor TMyReceiver.Create;
begin
 try
 inherited create;
  Except on E : Exception do
  begin

  end;

  end;
end;

procedure TMyReceiver.onDisabled(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  try

  Except on E : Exception do
  begin

  end;

  end;
end;

procedure TMyReceiver.onEnabled(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  try

  Except on E : Exception do
  begin

  end;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Filter: JIntentFilter;
begin
  try



  FMyListener := TMyReceiver.Create;
  FDeviceAdminReceiver := TJDeviceAdminReceiver.JavaClass.init;

  TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(FDeviceAdminReceiver, Filter);
  Except on E : Exception do
  begin
    showMessage(E.Message);
  end;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
  TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.unregisterReceiver(FDeviceAdminReceiver);
  Except on E : Exception do
  begin
    showMessage(E.Message);
  end;

  end;
end;

end.
```

When I run this application it fails to open showing :
"Unfortunately, DevicdAdmin01 has stopped."

Following are the logs related to this app from the bugreport.

```
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.embarcadero.DeviceAdmin01, PID: 24211
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.embarcadero.DeviceAdmin01/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:170)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity.onCreate(FMXNativeActivity.java:139)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
09-18 00:33:27.234 24211 24211 E AndroidRuntime: ... 10 more
09-18 00:33:27.238   861   876 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.embarcadero.DeviceAdmin01/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity
```

What could have gone wrong here ?

i will really appreciate your help to fix this..

Comment: The error is "Unable to find native library: main". Maybe you should fix that.

Comment: @nolaspeaker  Yes, I do not know how to fix this. Can you help me with some hint what needs a change to fix this ? is it the code or appmanifest ?  something to do with the sdkVersion mentioned in the manifest ?

Comment: Can you make a basic application that has only 1 form and no code? If you get the same error, then your IDE configuration isn't setup properly. Check your Tools->Options->SDK Manager tabsheets.

Comment: @nolaspeaker I tried this. I was able to compile and install an app with empty form. I figured out the issue was with my manifest file. thanks for the suggestions ! I will post the answer in sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find native library: main error was because of the missing information in the manifest file. The code to register the adminReceiver is wrong, but the app opens at least.

following is the new manifest file which solved the "Unable to find native library: main" issue :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.DevAdm02"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="DevAdm02" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">



        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="DevAdm02"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="DevAdm02" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />



        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"                 
                  android:label="DevAdm02"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                  android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                  android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Next I have to find out how to register the DeviceAdminReceiver class object. I am posting this as an answer because it solved the immediate issue which was java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main

Comment: That's interesting. So can you tell us what you changed in the manifest?

Comment: the following <meta-data> tag was missing in the manifest

`<!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
android:value="DevAdm02" />`